# jQuery hover to slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-slide-effects

*Check the bottom for revised edition*

Alright, here's the issue. I have a `li` with a `div` inside, and I'm trying to hover the `li` to get the `div` to slide up into view.

*Here's the HTML:*

```
<li id="one">
    <div>
        <h4>title</h4>
        <p>description</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

*Right now I have this in my CSS:*

```
#one div { display: none; }
```

*And this for my JS:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#one').hover(function() {
        $('#one > div').css({ display : 'block' });
    });

});
```

I know I could just used CSS psuedo `:hover` to make it pop up, but I thought if I wanted to to a slide effect then I might as well do it all in JS. The first problem is this isn't working :|. Once I get it to just show up I want to add a slide effect to it, and I'm not sure if this is the right way to approach doing that.

Thanks guys/gals

**revised**

*New JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#one').hover(function () {
        $('#one > div').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

This works! Although it comes down from the top, and I planned on having it come up from the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is that `slideUp()` in jQuery *hides* the selection and `slideDown()` *shows* the selection. To have an element slide up into view, you need to do your own `.animate()`.

```
CSS:
  #one {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 40px;
  }

  #one div { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
  }

jQuery:
  $('#one').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('div').animate({
            bottom: '0%'
        }, 'fast' );
    },function() {
        $(this).find('div').animate({
            bottom: '-100%'
        },'fast');
    }
  );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/mrzqK/

Comment: Yes! I knew there was some work around to it, but I just couldn't remember. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

what about using jQuery `slideUp` or `fadeIn`?

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

This code works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#one').hover(function () {
        $('#one > div').slideDown();
    });

});
```

Needs a bit of tweeking to make it look nice but it does slide down.

**edit**

Here is a site describing how to use animate to do what you want.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: This doesn't resolve the first issue with no being able to get the jquery to show the div on hover.

Comment: hang on.  i'll take a closer look

Comment: Actually T_T I forgot to link jQuery. Going to edit with the new issue in a sec.

Comment: See my edit.  works for me.  if this does not work for you then please let us know what errors you are getting.  btw: stupid question, you have included the jQuery.js as a script in your page right?

Comment: Just now included jQuery. I was working on two sites at the same time and forgot to add it to the second one. Check the OP for the new problem. I'll add your code and see what happens.

Comment: I am currently using your code, except slideToggle(). Anyway to change the direction is slides in from?

Comment: Hmmm, if you want to control the direction use 'animate' instead.  That will give you full control over direction and speed etc.

Answer (score 1):

you may do something like this

$(div).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000)

or even the animate property may solve your problems

more here

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide
api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

firstly you need to create a min-width and min-height or something because  li there is currently nothing to hover over.(just something to make the li have a presence put a red border on it and you'll see what I'm talking about.)

secondly I think you want to slideDown()... I think slideUp() will make it dissapear right?

I added a bg color for demo purposes.

hears a little demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/R9A3G/

If you're looking for a specific animation you may have to do some css tricks along with jquery .animate().

Comment: I have the li present on my version, just forgot to include that. I have it working now with slideToggle(), which is exactly how I want it. When you leave the li, it slide back away out of vision. Is there a way to change it to get it to slide from the bottom of the li instead of the top?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <style>#one div { display: none; }</style>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#one').hover(function() {

      $("#one").find("div").slideDown("slow");
    });
    $('#one').mouseout(function() {

      $("#one").find("div").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<div>
    <li id="one">
    <div>
        <h4>title</h4>
        <p>description</p>
    </div>
</li>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

TRY THIS