# Why isn't this JavaScript working? (JSFiddle I found on stackoverflow, but doesn't work when I put it in html)

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys! Sorry I didn't check the console...I have a pretty good grasp of HTML/CSS, but just starting to learn JavaScript, and knowing checking the console as well as implementing some of the help from the comments will definitely help my future JavaScript endeavors.

I'm trying to figure out why this code I found on stackoverflow isn't working for me. The code I'm wishing to implement is from this post: [jQuery hover to slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761729/jquery-hover-to-slide)

[Here is my HTML test page](http://ringpublications.net/stackoverflow/)

I can confirm that the JQuery library is loading, so I'm not sure why it'd work in JSFiddle.net, but not in my code. I'm hoping/thinking it's a small error that I'll 'doh' at, such as missing an end quote/bracket, but I can't find anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Think you have some weird char somewhere where youve implemented the script.

Comment: You have probably cut and paste from jsfiddle which is not a good idea.

Comment: Just delete the last couple lines of the script, including the `</script>` tag, then retype them manually. The error will go away.

Comment: @bwheeler96 the code is available and linked to

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Questions shouldn't rely on external links.

Comment: Nim I don't want to go to your website, post the relevant snippet here.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure you have no weird chars in your code. Best to put it in notepad or something...